# Android правильная архитектура для приложения с сетевыми запросами

Tags: java, android, ооп, service, шаблоны-проектирования

Пишу приложение, которое получает с Web сервиса xml, и выводит его содержимое в ListView. Поскольку и java в целом, и Android в частности для меня новые вещи, приходится перерабатывать горы информации, часто устаревшей. С шаблонами проектирования тоже знаком очень поверхностно. Сейчас у меня все работает, но нет уверенности что я все делаю верно. Пожалуйста укажите что не так в моем решении, и какие шаблоны проектирования я использовал.

Мое приложение состоит из Application, Activity и Сервиса.
Я начитался про то, как плохо использовать AsyncTask и поэтому решил использовать Сервисы.

Application в onCreate создает ServiceHelper и предоставляет к нему доступ.
К Activity подключен интерфейс, слушатель ответа от сервиса.
При нажатии кнопки в Activity, ServiceHelper создает интент и запускает сервис.
Сервис после завершения работы отправляет результат работы через интерфейс ServiceCallbackListener в бандле.

Activity по событию onServiceCallback считывает результат из бандла.

Затем я понял, что в случае, когда Callback от сервиса приходит в остановленное приложение, то результат пропадает в никуда.

Для решения этой проблемы я сделал так, что сервис сохраняет в ServiceHelper бандл с результатом работы, а Activity, после обработки коллбека сообщает хелперу, что кэш можно очистить. Теперь у меня Activity, по событию onPostResume спрашивает у ServiceHelper, обрабатывает ли еще сервис запрос с указанным id, если нет, то нет ли для этого id данных, и если есть, грузит их в ListView и сообщает хелперу, что данные с таким то id нужно удалить.

Все хорошо, но эта реализация навеяна статьей https://habrahabr.ru/post/144275/, которой уже пять лет. Я слышал, что сейчас в Android используют Loaderы, ретрофит, rxJava, и много других страшных слов, отсюда возникли сомнения, не горожу ли я велосипеды там, где надо использовать готовые объекты?

Comment: Прошу прощения за оффтоп а не дадите ссылку на статью?

Comment: Почему же оффтоп, со ссылкой думаю даже понятнее будет, что я тут написал. https://habrahabr.ru/post/144275/

Comment: Что вас не устраивает в вашей текущей реализации? Что не работает (например, повороты экрана плохо/неправильно/неоптимально/не поддерживаются вовсе)? Зачем вам городить ретрофиты, rx и т.д.? Какой профит вы ожидаете? Использование технологии ради технологии смысла не имеет.

Comment: На настоящий момент все работает, если что-то не работает, то я этого еще не заметил. Понимаете, поскольку я на этапе изучения, мне хотелось бы сразу научиться делать правильно, а не переучиваться потом, а поскольку в моем окружении нет специалистов, с которыми можно обсудить этот вопрос, я и обратился сюда. Чтобы меня покритиковали и ткнули носом, что учить.

Comment: По опыту могу сказать, что эти страшные слова отлично работают на helloworld'ах и pet проектах. Если возникает какой-то неочевидный кейс, то получается не профит, а головная боль. В андроиде слишком много ограничений на жизненный цикл, на количество памяти, на процессорное время и многие технологии, которые пытаются придумать для андроида люди java-мира с их энтерпрайзами и безграничными ресурсами выходят боком в андроиде. Я не говорю, что все эти страшные слова плохи, но на изучение этих технологий и применение в своем проекте уйдет довольно много времени. Серебряной пули нет.

Comment: В качестве конструктива почитайте https://frogermcs.github.io/ статьи про Dagger 2, там и другие фреймворки/технологии используются. И обратите внимание на комментарии, что проблемы есть и как их удается или не удается решать.

Comment: Реализовал подобное. Хотелось по фэншую. [Вот ссылка](https://github.com/zavbak/ANITSMART) Использую ContentProvider, EventBus, Rx, Service. Пытался реализовать как MVP структуру.

Answer (score 1):

`Service` есть смысл использовать только если обмен информацией ведется постоянно,в том числе тогда, когда приложение выключено, если же только в момент, когда приложение работает гораздо лучше, легче и проще ограничиться обычным `Thread`.

`ListView` вещь устаревшая уже, если не пишите под Android 2.3 то используется `RecyclerView`. Все то же самое, работает быстрее, `ViewHolder` в коробке и фич больше.

`Retrofit` вещь замечательная, но если не используется полноценный хороший REST API, а вместо этого просто пуляем данные обычным постом, то лучше ограничиться `OkHttp` библиотекой. Если требуется преобразовывать из `JSON` большие данные по объектам есть библиотека `GSON` для упрощения процесса, которая тоже не всегда нужна.

В бандлах данные хранить по-моему незачем. Можно передавать напрямую из потока/сервиса во фрагмент/активити.

Comment: «В бандлах данные хранить по-моему незачем. Можно передавать напрямую из потока/сервиса во фрагмент/активити.» я и передаю напрямую, но что делать если активити-получатель, в момент получения данных спит, находится на паузе или вообще уничтожено?

Comment: Проверить его на null, можно отслеживать state активити, с этим как -то проблем нет. При этом обновлять данные гораздо проще.

Comment: Ну проверили, убедились. Куда данные девать? Вот сейчас я кладу их в бандл, когда активити проснется, оно спросит, нет ли для него данных, и получит этот бандл.

Comment: Ок. А потом я вырубил сервис и убил приложение. И где данные? В таком случае если данных совсем мало SharedPreferences, если много SQLite

Comment: Вообще обычно SQLite для таких дел все же юзают, иначе если пользователь без интернета, то отображать нечего совсем, в противном случае он хоть со старыми данными сможет что-то сделать.

Comment: Если данные должны попасть в БД, то да. А если это например поисковый запрос к веб сервису, результаты которого надо показать пользователю в списке. Тогда, если дело дошло до закрытия приложения, пользователь не удивится, что надо повторно делать запрос.

Comment: Ну пожалуй в таком случае бандл действительно имеет смысл. Ровно также как и случаи вроде переворота экрана.